# Cant get X-custom-header from response ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, http, header, cors

I'm using `react-fetching-library` to send requests to the server and I want to read response headers from my ReactJS application.

What I do is trying to read them from Headers object (`headers.entries()`) after fetching but there are only two headers I can access: `content-length` and `content-type`.

Preflight `OPTIONS` request has following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Actual response has only `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header

I want to read X-custom-header headers from my js code. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've finally managed to solve this problem

All you need to do is to add this response header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *,Authorization,X-custom-header
```

From now you can access custom headers from your JS

Comment: This list should include response headers, so it never makes sense to have `Authorization` in there as it's a request header.

Comment: Thanks @Volok, this save my a lot of time :)